# Laravel Sync error

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationships

I am running the following code,

```
if( $organisation->save() ) {

        if(isset($members)) {
            $organisation->users()->sync($members);
        }

        if(isset($teams)) {
            $organisation->teams()->sync($teams);
        }

        if(isset($teams)) {
            $organisation->clients()->sync($clients);
        }

        if(isset($projects)) {
            $organisation->projects()->sync($projects);
        }

        $organisation->load('users');
        $organisation->load('teams');
        $organisation->load('clients');
        $organisation->load('projects');

        return Response::make($organisation, 200);

    }
```

I am am getting the following error when I try and sync `$projects`,

the array looks like this,

`[0] => 6` so a very very simple array. My relationships in the models look like this,

**Organisation**

```
public function projects()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Project');
}
```

**Projects**

```
public function organisations()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Organisation', 'organisation_id');
}
```

As you can see I an organisation can have many projects. I cannot see a reason why I would be getting the following error,

> Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder::sync()

Comment: Are you sure you don't have any column in table for `Organisation` with `projects` name ?

Comment: There is no column called projects in the organisation table

Answer (score 28, accepted):

As it's many-to many relationship in both functions you need to use `belongsToMany`, so you should use:

```
public function projects()
{
    return $this->belongsToMany('Project');
}
```

instead of:

```
public function projects()
{
    return $this->hasMany('Project');
}
```

`sync()` works only for many to many relationship